# Method sometimes shall returns value sometime not. How to refactor it?

Tags: java

An interface looks like below:

```
public interface RunnableAction
{
    Optional<?> run(final Action action, final Context Context);
}
```

And a lot of diffrent implementations of this interface.

The problem is:

Some of the Actions need to return some data, e.g. ActionReadFromFile but some of them return something for no good reason (in that case I return Optional.empty()), e.g. ActionCloseWindow. How to make it a little better? i.e. return when needed and don’t return anything when nothing meaningful can or should be returned. This should make the code cleaner by eliminating the likes of 'return Optional.empty()’ or ‘.get()’.

Any advices or hints?

Comment: apply *Tell, don't ask!* principle.

Answer (score 0):

I think that better solution would be by going c++ style :D
Do not return value, pass some value instead and let it change in the method. For example, pass collection of desirable data. After that call, collection would be empty or not:

```
public interface RunnableAction<T>
{
    void run(final Action action, final Context Context, Collection<T> pickedData);
}
```

Comment: I did something like that but not with additional parameters but I have extended an Action interface like below:

public  interface Action
{
    void setResult(Object result);

    Object getResult();

    <T> T getResult(Class<T> type);
}

Answer (score 0):

Either use generics and `Void` for the implementations which return nothing

```
public interface RunnableAction<T>
{
    T run(final Action action, final Context Context);
}

class Foo implements RunnableAction<Void>
{
    public Void run(final Action action, final Context Context)
    {
        //do something

        return null; // Void is not instantiable, so return null
    }
}
```

or have two types of action:

```
public interface CallableAction<T>
{
    T run(final Action action, final Context Context);
}

public interface RunnableAction
{
    void run(final Action action, final Context Context);
}
```

Comment: Where is a difference bettween returning null and Optional.empty? For me both are bed.